# Add Default value while grouping elements in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am working with Pandas dataframe and my data has EmployeeNo, Payable and Amount as columns.

```
      EmpNo     Payable    Amount

      01        Salary     20000
      01        Salary     2000
      01        Bonus      150

      02        Salary     15000

      03        Salary     10000
      03        Bonus      50
      03        Bonus      150

      04        Salary     12000
      04        Salary     3000
```

I wanted to group based on Salary and Bonus for each employee and sum up all the salaries and bonus for each employee. I wrote this code :

```
df_2 = df.groupby([ 'EmpNo', 'Payable'])['Amount'].sum()
```

But it doesn't show Bonus for each and every employee.

I want my output to show 0 as a default value if Bonus is not assigned to any employee in the following format:

```
      EmpNo     Payable    Amount
      
      01        Salary     22000
                Bonus      150

      02        Salary     15000
                Bonus      0

      03        Salary     10000
                Bonus      200

      04        Salary     15000
                Bonus      0
```

Answer (score 5):

Add [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df_2 = df.groupby([ 'EmpNo', 'Payable'])['Amount'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
print (df_2)
EmpNo  Payable
1      Bonus        150
       Salary     22000
2      Bonus          0
       Salary     15000
3      Bonus        200
       Salary     10000
4      Bonus          0
       Salary     15000
dtype: int64
```

If need convert to `DataFrame` add [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df_2 = (df.groupby([ 'EmpNo', 'Payable'])['Amount']
          .sum()
          .unstack(fill_value=0)
          .stack()
          .reset_index(name='Amount'))
print (df_2)
   EmpNo Payable  Amount
0      1   Bonus     150
1      1  Salary   22000
2      2   Bonus       0
3      2  Salary   15000
4      3   Bonus     200
5      3  Salary   10000
6      4   Bonus       0
7      4  Salary   15000
```

Comment: df.pivot_table('Amount', 'EmpNo', 'Payable', 'sum', 0).stack() would be another route to the first option.

Comment: @Jamie - Yop, in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`df.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
In [393]: df.pivot_table(index='EmpNo', columns='Payable', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
Out[393]: 
   EmpNo Payable  Amount
0      1   Bonus     150
1      1  Salary   22000
2      2   Bonus       0
3      2  Salary   15000
4      3   Bonus     200
5      3  Salary   10000
6      4   Bonus       0
7      4  Salary   15000
```